# metal causes memory use of kernel_task increases dramatically

Tags: ios, macos, metal

Is it necessary to free MTLBuffer as C language does, and how ? I am a newcomer of metal. Thanks for viewing my question.
I have tried to set the used MLTBuffer to nil and used [mtl_buffer setPurgeableState:MTLPurgeableStateEmpty] methods, where mtl_buffer is a variable of MTLBuffer, but neither worked.

Comment: Are you using ARC? If so, the buffer object and its underlying allocation will be freed when there are no more references to the buffer object, unless you're using `-newBufferWithBytesNoCopy:...` to wrap a page-aligned chunk of memory you've allocated, in which case you need to manually free it (probably in the deallocator block). It might be helpful to see how you're creating your buffers.

Comment: In my project, I built the codes, which was written in object C, into a static lib(named x.a) under osx system. And the metal shader functions was called in x.a, and x.a was used in a c program.  Finally, I used [MLTBuffer release] method, and the problem was solved. Does that means ARC is not used ?

Comment: That's correct. If you are manually calling `release`, you're not using ARC.

Comment: @warrenm, anther question: Is it necessary for MTLDevice or MTLCommandQueue to call release method after the whole program finished?

Comment: This isn't specific to Metal. _Any_ time you `alloc` or `new` an object in Objective-C, there should be a corresponding `release` or `autorelease`.